# How to copy/transfer a file from windows server path to linux server path?

Tags: java, linux, smb

I have tried the below code:

```
String url = "smb://remotehost/SharedPath/Comp/NG/";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth2 = new 
NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null,"user", "password");
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles())
{
  if(f.getName().contains("Test")) //successfully reads the file
  {
    System.out.println("test...."+f);
    filename= f.getUncPath();
    System.out.println("filename...."+filename);
    sftpChannel.put(filename, remoteDirectory); // throws exception
  }  
}
```

Above code results in exception as follows:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\remotehost\SharedPath\comp\NG\Test.txt (Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password)`

Please note:

- I am able to read the files present in the remote server using the above code but not able to copy or transfer the file from remote server path to Linux server path.
- As the connection to remote server and linux server was successful, I tried to directly copy the file from remote path to linux server path using `sftpchannel.put()` but it throws exception.
- Once connected using smb, will we not be able to connect directly to shared path using below url? `String url = "//remotehost/SharedPath/Comp/NG/";`

Please note: I am connecting to Linux server using jsch library and I am able to successfully connect to Linux server using sftpChannel.connect(); and also able to put the file from my local machine to Linux server using sftpChannel.put(localpath, linuxpath);  and To connect to windows server I am using smbFile. I am able to connect but not able to copy the file from windows to Linux server path.  I tried using sftpChannel.put(filename, remoteDirectory);  for the same but it resulted in exception. At this particular step I assumed that as the connection to windows server is successful I will be able to copy the files as well. I am able to read the file but not copy. Not sure why this is happening.

Can anyone provide me the proper steps to do this?

Comment: When reading the directory you use that `SmbFile` class and provide authentication credentials for it, so it works. When trying to copy you use that `sftChannel` which is a completely different class. How should it know the authentication credentials? I'm not familiar with these classes, but you probably have to read the content of your file via the `SmbFile` class and store it in memory or in a local file, and then sftp copy it to the destination from your memory array or local file.

Comment: As I see the `SmbFile` class has a `getInputStream()` method so its InputStream can be used to read the file. I can not see in your example what is the type of this `sftChannel` variable

Comment: @BalázsNemes Sorry I have not provided the complete code. I just provided the code that resulted in exception.

Comment: @BalázsNemes  I have added some more information in the note section. Hope that gives you a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the type of `sftpChannel` is `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp`. Then the following method will do the copy for you. Of course you have to pass properly initialized `SmbFile` and `ChannelSftp` objects as parameters.

```
public void copyFromSmbToSftp(SmbFile smbFile, ChannelSftp channelSftp, String destPath) throws IOException, SftpException {
    try(BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(smbFile.getInputStream());
        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(channelSftp.put(destPath))){
      byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
      int bytesRead;
      while((bytesRead=inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length))!=-1){
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    }
  }
```